# Optimizing AngularJS ng-repeat for many items and fields

Tags: javascript, angularjs, optimization, checkbox, angularjs-ng-repeat

Recently I had to make an interface that necessitated many items with numerous checkbox fields to be displayed and interacted with (here is a link to a screengrab of a small portion of such a list https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTTvT.png).

My issue was that AngularJS would get unreasonably slow pretty quickly. My question is **What steps could one take to optimize ng-repeat and displaying items with many fields?**

I have tried with varying degrees of improvement (based on what I could come up with and other stackoverflow posts):

- Formatting the data before it gets to the view so as to not use any AngularJS filtering/sorting.
- Simplifying the data as much as possible (checkbox fields being arrays of booleans, etc)
- Splitting the data into groups that, when clicked, loaded the relevant items (hence the gray bars in the picture). This is more of a pragmatic solution though, rather than straight up AngularJS optimization.
- Lazy loading scroll, scrolling to the bottom of the screen loads more items below the fold (also, more of a pragmatic solution).
- Using directives to dynamically generate a form, and then use jquery for saving the data after manipulation. Without $watch on items anymore it certainly was more efficient, but largely defeated the benefits of using AngularJS.

Thank you, and hopefully this question and its answers can serve as a good resource for AngularJS specific techniques one can use in such a situation.

Comment: I had amortization table with 360 rows and it worked just fine. How many rows do you have?

Comment: I just saw the image. It shouldnt be trouble. Show us your code so we can see where improvements can be made.

Comment: My 'tables' (used divs as cell paint refresh can be brutal with large tables) were around that size as well, though it was more the fields slowing things down.

Comment: @Nihat I see a comment in my inbox that I voted you down but I don't see the comment here, nor your answer. Sorry if I accidentally did so, I did appreciate the response. Egg on my face.

Comment: That is ok. I removed my comment about suggesting ng-infinite-scroll thing because that answer was just a hack, not really addressing your question. Peace :)

Comment: Some context on this app might help. I count 33 (custom?) checkboxes a line, which means 33 scopes. What are you building?

Comment: @MikeRobinson Hoo boy, how to put this... generically speaking, we are developing this app/tool for a (very corporate) client. It marriages together all these complicated workflows with many constructs that relate to one another in nearly absurdly intricate ways. These constructs are generally many-to-many relationships with various rules, and they are created/edited by admins. The picture you saw was one of the simpler views in the admin panel where one defines the relationships for one kind of construct, the grid column groups representing other (arbitrarily large) groups of constructs.

Comment: Have you already seen this? http://blog.scalyr.com/2013/10/31/angularjs-1200ms-to-35ms/

Comment: If you have content that will not change it may be worth trying to use one time binding (wich :: syntax) to improve performance